# Is my jsconfig.json not working in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have added a `jsconfig.json` in the root of my javascript project to try and exclude some build files as well as set some path mappings but nothing seems to happen. Part of the problem is that I'm not sure what the expected outcome is when using a `jsconfig.json`, I've read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) for it but it does not demonstrate any of the results.

Can someone provide me with a small and working `jsconfig.json` with a description of what it *actually* does? So that I can use it to verify that it actually works in my project as well.

Or, does someone know of a way to verify that a `jsconfig.json` is working/picked up by VS Code?

Comment: You wrote, "but nothing seems to happen." What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @shaun-luttin For the `exclude` property I was hoping it would exclude files and folders from the Explorer view as well as be ignored by intellisense. As for the path mapping I was hoping it would resolve (for intellisense) some custom import statements in the project.

Answer (score 6):

In my project i was using jsconfig.json file for accesss the file imports directly from the ./src directory from wherever i am trying to import.

My jsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src"
     },
     "include": [
         "src"
      ]
}
```

**include:**

> If no include attribute is present, then this defaults to including all files in the containing directory and subdirectories. When a include attribute is specified, only those files are included

**baseUrl:**

> This gives the base directory for the file import path

this is my project structure where i have used jsconfig.json

[image]

so if i need to import a function from `src/util/auth_util.js` inside `src/component/Login/index.js`

inside src/component/Login/index.js

> src/component/Login/index.js :
>
> > `import { userLogin } from 'util/auth_util.js'`

import statement if jsconfig.json as mentioned above not used

> src/component/Login/index.js :
>
> > `import { userLogin } from '../../util/auth_util.js'`